# How are browsers affected by a large number of xhr requests over time?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

**Here's the scenario:**

I have a web app run in Google Chrome's kiosk mode that makes an ajax call once every second using jQuery. The call returns true or false based on a condition.  After about 3 days, Chrome is using an exorbitant amount of memory and is very, very slow.  I've checked javascript variables using the dev tools profiler and even deleted all my window.xxxx variables and emptied the body of the page.  Chrome doesn't release the memory until I close and reopen it.

**The Question:** 
What are the effects of having a large number or requests in a browser over time?

***Note:** Of course there are easy to implement work-arounds, like refreshing the page every so often etc., but learning the internals would be more helpful in this situation and could prove useful in other situations as well